How to trigger the azure pipeline on pull request
I have a resource section in my pipeline through which I want to trigger my current  pipeline when the source pipeline, which is pull request automated is completed.
But the issue is that although the PR automated pipeline "pqr" is completed the current pipeline is not getting triggered.
I used below code
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: abc
      source: pqr
      project: kvi
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - "*"
        pr:
          branches:
            include:
              - "*"

I get error:

/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 17, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'pr'
74518


You can remove the pr section of your yaml. Merging a PR on a branch automatically triggers a push event on it, so it will execute your pipeline.

Yes but it's impossible to tell if the change is related to a pull request or not - any commit will trigger the pipeline.

Most of the time PR are merged on the main branch, so the branch is supposed to have a policy that prevents pushes other than related to a PR, but yes any commit will trigger the pipeline.


I want to trigger my current pipeline when the source pipeline, which is pull request automated is completed

In short:

For builds in the same repository use a pull request trigger

For builds in different repositories or projects consider using a pipeline resource with a tagfilter


Using a pull request trigger
Example of a pr trigger:
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - features/*
    - main
    exclude:
    - features/experimental/*
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md

Using tags and pipeline resources
In the source pipeline (pqr) add a task to add a tag to the build - for example, tag PULL_REQUEST:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]PULL_REQUEST"
  displayName: 'Apply pull request tag'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')

And then configure the branches and tags that will trigger the target pipeline:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: abc
      source: pqr
      project: kvi
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - "*"
      tags:
        - PULL_REQUEST


/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 17, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'pr' 74518

because of the resource.pipelines section does not support pr: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline-trigger?view=azure-pipelines#trigger-enabled-branches-stages-tags


Got it.. Is there any way I can trigger when there is a pr on any of these pipelines?

@kiranitagi there are no pull requests triggers for other repositories or projects. The easiest workaround is to tag a build, as mentioned in my answer.
